# Photoshop plugin sdk sample - listner not working

Tags: c++, plugins, sdk, photoshop

I am trying to build and use the photoshop plugin sample called listener that comes with the [sdk](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html).

The documentation doesn't say anything on error handling (at least I couldn't find any). Of course tried to google the issue didn't have any success.

What I did is download vs 2015 community and installed what is neccessary to compile the plugin code, and then I just created a shortcut to the 8li file inside the photoshop plugin folder.

After photoshop loads up an alert pops up saying there was an issue loading the plugin and that I can see the reason in help -> system info. So I did and it writes the following error:
   Listener NO VERSION -  - from the file “Listener.8li”

I didn't change anything in the code its the same as I extacted it from the zipped folder. I have to also point out that I tried vs 2013 which is the recommended version for building the plugins but vs 2015 is suppose to suffice in anyway it gave the same results.

If anyone has any idea where I should check or what to do I will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why.
You need to build the whole solution ("BuildAll.sln"), not just the project.
And then you can copy or make a short cut of samplecode\Output\Win\Debug64\Listener.8li

Comment: Am sorry I didn't answer any earlier but it turned out that I was targeting the wrong architecture (32bit instead of 64bit)